A RenderSliverPadding expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox
In my Flutter application, I'm developing a chatbot using flutter_chat_ui. This app can fetch initial messages and display them, but the moment I perform onTap on any of the initial messages, I'm getting errors.
When I click on any initial messages, it should add new messages to the message list and display them, but instead, I'm receiving this error:

Error: A RenderSliverPadding expected a child of type RenderSliver but
received a child of type RenderErrorBox.

RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they coordinate with their children during layout and painting. For example, a RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.
ChatDemo class:
class _ChatScreenDemo2 extends State<ChatScreenDemo2> {
  final GlobalKey<SliverAnimatedListState> _sliverAnimatedListKey =
      GlobalKey<SliverAnimatedListState>();
  ChatScreenViewModel chatScreenVM = ChatScreenViewModel();
  ChatController? _chatController;

  List<types.TextMessage> messages = [];
  final String User = 'user_1'; // Example user ID
  final String Admin = 'user_2';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    chatScreenVM.fetchInitialMessage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Chat'),
      ),
      // body: Column(
      //   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      //   children: [
      //     Flexible(
      //       child: Observer(builder: (_) {
      //         return Chat(
      //           messages: chatScreenVM.initialMessageList.reversed.toList(),
      //           onSendPressed: _handleSendPressed,
      //           user: types.User(id: User),
      //           onMessageTap: _handleMessageTap,
      //         );
      //       }),
      //     ),
      //   ],
      // ),

      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, // Set a fixed height

        child: Observer(builder: (_) {
          return Chat(
            messages: chatScreenVM.initialMessageList.reversed.toList(),
            onSendPressed: _handleSendPressed,
            user: types.User(id: User),
            onMessageTap: _handleMessageTap,
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleSendPressed(types.PartialText message) {
    final newMessage = types.TextMessage(
      author: types.User(id: User),
      createdAt: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      id: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
      text: message.text,
    );
    setState(() {
      messages.add(newMessage);
    });
  }

  void _handleMessageTap(BuildContext context, types.Message message) {
    if (message is types.TextMessage) {
      final newMessage = types.TextMessage(
        author: types.User(id: "user_1"),
        id: message.id,
        createdAt: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - 10000,
        text: message.text,
      );
      setState(() {
        chatScreenVM.updateMessageList(newMessage);
        print("${message.id}");
        print("Cliked");
        chatScreenVM.fetchResponse(message.id);
      });
    }
  }
}


Chat screen view model:
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:echarak/Modal/chat_screen_inital_message_response_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';

import '../Modal/chat_screen_initial_message_model.dart';
import '../constant/base_url.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_chat_types/flutter_chat_types.dart' as types;


part 'chat_screen_view_model.g.dart';


class ChatScreenViewModel = _ChatScreenViewModel with _$ChatScreenViewModel;

abstract class _ChatScreenViewModel with Store{
  final FlutterSecureStorage secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage(); // Initialize secure storage

  @observable
  ObservableList<types.TextMessage> initialMessageList = ObservableList();

  @action
  Future<void> updateMessageList(types.TextMessage value) async{
    try{
      initialMessageList.add(value);
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @action
  Future<void> fetchInitialMessage()async{
    try {
      final token = await secureStorage.read(key: 'token');
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('${AppUrls.BASE_URL}/GetTer'),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token', //
        },
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final List<dynamic> responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
        // Map response to initialMessageList
        initialMessageList = ObservableList<types.TextMessage>.of(
          responseBody.map((item) {
            final chatScreenInitial = ChatScreenInitial.fromJson(item);
            return types.TextMessage(
              author: types.User(id: "user_2"),
              id: chatScreenInitial.id.toString(),
              createdAt:  DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - 10000,
              text: chatScreenInitial.type_of_query ?? '', // Fallback if null
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
        print("Initial Message list:$responseBody");
      }
      else {
        print("Error: ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @action
  Future<void> fetchResponse(String id) async{
    try {
      final token = await secureStorage.read(key: 'token');
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('${AppUrls.BASE_URL}/GetsubTer/$id'),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token', //
        },
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final List<dynamic> responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
        final responseList = ObservableList<types.TextMessage>.of(
          responseBody.map((item) {
            final chatScreenInitialResonse = ChatScreenInitialResponse.fromJson(item);
            return types.TextMessage(
              author: types.User(id: "user_2"),
              id: chatScreenInitialResonse.id.toString(),
              createdAt:  DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch - 10000,
              text: chatScreenInitialResonse.subTypeOfQuery ?? '', // Fallback if null
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
        initialMessageList.addAll(responseList);
        print("Initial Message list:$responseBody");
      }
      else {
        print("Error: ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}

